# Get equality masks for all values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I created the following numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[3, 0, 3],
              [1, 3, 3],
              [1, 1, 3]])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

If I do `a == 0` I get:

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

And if I do `a == 1` I get:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

And so on. But if I want to get an array containing all the masks relative to all conditions `a == n` with `n` belonging to `b`, how should I proceed?

`np.array([a == n for n in b])` does what I want but doesn't seem very *numpythonic*. I also tried `a == b` which simply returns `False`.

Comment: Try broadcasting, `b[:,None,None]==a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `a == b[:,None,None]` and broadcasting takes care of the rest:

```
>>> a == b[:,None,None]
array([[[False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True]]])
```